# Labeling the thequestion and the parts in a storing box

Tags: boxes, labels, exam

I'm a typesetting tests with key answers. The questions have parts. What I want is to make `\thequestion` appear only once and the `\thepartno` follow without the question label. For example:

Question 1 - this is question 1
a) item a
b) item b

key answer

Queston 1 - a) item a b) item b

Besides, when a question does not have parts, it still shows a nonexisting part label.
Here the pdf output:

[image]

Currently, I'm typesetting the labels of the question and the parts in the solution environment, so when the answer key will have the labels of the question once and then the parts.

Here is the WME, as far as I've got.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\printanswers
\unframedsolutions

% Storing box
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers\hbox{}

% Seting storing box
\renewenvironment{solution}{\noindent\global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox\bgroup%
    \unhbox\allanswers%
        {\textbf{\thequestion-}}%
        {\large\textbf{\thepartno)}}%
        }%
    {\egroup}

% Unboxing stored box
\newcommand{\showallanswers}{\noindent\unhbox\allanswers}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.01pt}

\begin{questions}

\question this is question 1

    \begin{parts}
\item item a
        \begin{solution}
        solution of item a
        \end{solution}

\item item b
        \begin{solution}
        solution of item b
        \end{solution}

\item item c
        \begin{solution}
        solution of item c
        \end{solution}
\item item d
        \begin{solution}
        ~solution of item d
        \end{solution}
    \end{parts}

\question this is question 2
        \begin{solution}
         $\dfrac{1}{2}$
         
        \end{solution}

\question this is question 3

    \begin{parts}
\item item a
        \begin{solution}
        solution of item a
        \end{solution}

\item item b
        \begin{solution}
        solution of item b
        \end{solution}

\item item c
        \begin{solution}
        solution of item c
        \end{solution}
\item item d
        \begin{solution}
        solution of item d
        \end{solution}
    \end{parts}
    
\question this is question 4
        \begin{solution}
        this is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long solution for question 4
        \end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{multicols}

\vskip20pt
\begin{center}
{\Huge \textsc{Answer Key}}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.01pt}

\showallanswers
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```